# Custom views filter to filter nodes by field in a separate table

Tags: views, 8

The module I'm trying to build is a very simplified replacement for the Flag module because it is still in beta. The only functionality I need is the ability to favourite some content, which I have already replicated. I have a table that stores the `nid` of the content being favourited under a column called `entity_id` and `uid` of the user doing the favouriting.

I'm trying to have a views filter available when creating views of node content that will filter the view by if a node has been favourited or not. So I need to filter the nodes by if their `nid` appears in my custom `favourites` table. I have the filter defined so it is available to views of node content. I can't seem to figure out the correct way to configure the handler class to have the filter actually work though.

I know I'm doing something wrong here, I don't fully understand how to build the query I want in this use case. I have the filter added to a view of node content and the table `favourites` has a single row that connects the user with `uid` 1 to a node.

**favourites.module**

```php
function favourites_views_data_alter(array &$data) {
  $data["node"]["favourites_relationship"] = [
    "title" => t("Favourited Node"),
    "help" => t("Limit results to only those entity favourited."),
    "relationship" => [
      "group" => t("Favourites"),
      "label" => t("Favourites"),
      "base" => "favourites",
      "base field" => "entity_id",
      "relationship table" => "node_field_data",
      "relationship field" => "nid",
      "id" => "standard",
    ],
  ];

  $data["node_field_data"]["is_favourited"] = [
    "title" => t("Is Favourited"),
    "help" => t("If the content has been favourited."),
    "filter" => [
      "label" => t("Is Favourited"),
      "field" => "nid",
      "id" => "favourites_is_favourited_filter",
    ],
  ];

}
```

**FavouritesViewRelationship.php**

```php
namespace Drupal\favourites\Plugin\views\relationship;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\PageCache\ResponsePolicy\KillSwitch;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\relationship\RelationshipPluginBase;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\favourites\FavouritesServiceInterface;

/**
 * Provides a views relationship to select favourited content by a favourite.
 *
 * @ViewsRelationship("favourites_relationship")
 */
class FavouritesViewRelationship extends RelationshipPluginBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function defineOptions() {
    $options = parent::defineOptions();
    $options['favourite'] = ['default' => NULL];
    $options['required'] = ['default' => TRUE];
    $options['user_scope'] = ['default' => 'current'];

    return $options;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function query() {
    if (!($favourite = $this->getFavourite())) {
      return;
    }

    $this->definition['extra'][] = [
      'field' => 'favourite_id',
      'value' => $favourite->id(),
      'numeric' => TRUE,
    ];

    parent::query();
  }

  /**
   * Get the favourite of the relationship.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\favourites\FavouritesServiceInterface|null
   *   The favourite being selected by in the view.
   */
  public function getFavourite() {
    $favourite = $this->favouritesService->getFavouriteById($this->options['favourite']);
    return $favourite;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how much of the `FavouritesViewRelationship` class is really needed, I pulled it from the Flag module and tried to adapt it to my module while trying to get the filter working.

**IsFavouritedFilter.php**

```php
namespace Drupal\favourites\Plugin\views\filter;

use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\filter\FilterPluginBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\DisplayPluginBase;
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;
use Drupal\views\Views;

/**
 * Filters by given list of node by whether it has been favourited.
 *
 * @ingroup views_filter_handlers
 *
 * @ViewsFilter("favourites_is_favourited_filter")
 */
class IsFavouritedFilter extends FilterPluginBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function init(ViewExecutable $view, DisplayPluginBase $display, array &$options = NULL) {
    parent::init($view, $display, $options);
    $this->valueTitle = $this->t("Is Favourited Filter");
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function defineOptions() {
    $options = parent::defineOptions();
    $options["value"] = ["default" => 1];
    $options["relationship"] = ["default" => "favourites_relationship"];

    return $options;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildOptionsForm(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::buildOptionsForm($form, $form_state);

    $form["value"]["#type"] = "radios";
    $form["value"]["#title"] = $this->t("Status");
    $form["value"]["#options"] = [
      "All" => $this->t("All"),
      1 => $this->t("Favourited"),
      0 => $this->t("Not favourited"),
    ];
    $form["value"]["#default_value"] = isset($this->options["value"]) ? $this->options["value"] : 0;

    // Workaround for bug in Views: $no_operator class property has no effect.
    unset($form["operator"]);
    unset($form["expose"]["use_operator"]);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function query() {
    $this->ensureMyTable();
    $config = [
      "table" => "favourites",
      "field" => "entity_id",
      "left_table" => "node_field_data",
      "left_field" => "nid",
      "operator" => "=",
    ];
    $join = Views::pluginManager("join")->createInstance("standard", $config);

    $this->query->addRelationship("favs", $join, "node_field_data");
    $this->query->addWhere(0, $this->tableAlias . ".nid", "favs.entity_id", "=");
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you find some specific problem with the Flag module that doesn't work for you?  The current D8/9 flag module is marked beta but can certainly handle the case of marking nodes as favorites without any trouble.

Comment: @PatrickKenny unfortunately the client we are creating this for doesn't want us using beta modules for the site.